# undefined method `has_index_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I think I've tried every single "Undefined Method" question solutions on StackOverflow but still haven't found one that works for my situation...

I have a model named "Has" and I'm thinking that my problem may be related to the "s" on the end of that.  I keep getting this error anytime I try to load the has/new url.  /has works just fine.  Just not new...

undefined method `has_index_path' for #<#:0x007ff3bbaa8d48>

Has.rb:

```
class Has < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :bathroom_count, :bedroom_count, :neighborhood, :price, :property_type
  belongs_to :trader
end
```

has_controller.rb:

```
class HasController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @has = Has.all
  end

  def show
    @has = Has.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @has = Has.new
  end

  def create
    @has = Has.new(params[:has])
    if @has.save
      flash[:success] = "New Listing Created!"
      redirect_to (:back)
    else
      redirect_to (:back)
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @has.destroy
  end
end
```

view (new.html.erb) (using simple_form, obviously and that's working just fine on other "new" views")

```
<div class="center hero-unit">
<%= simple_form_for (@has) do |f| %>
    <%= f.association :trader%>
    <%= f.input :price %>
    <%= f.input :bathroom_count %>
    <%= f.input :bedroom_count %>
    <%= f.input :property_type %>
    <%= f.input :neighborhood %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb:

```
Algotest::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :traders
  resources :wants
  resources :has

  root to: 'static_pages#index'

  match '/add_traders', to: 'traders#new'
  match '/traders', to: 'traders#index'
  match '/add_has', to: 'has#new'
  match '/has', to: 'has#index'
  match '/add_wants', to: 'wants#new'
  match '/wants', to: 'wants#index'
end
```

EDIT: Here's the rake routes output:

```
    traders GET    /traders(.:format)          traders#index
            POST   /traders(.:format)          traders#create
     new_trader GET    /traders/new(.:format)      traders#new
    edit_trader GET    /traders/:id/edit(.:format) traders#edit
         trader GET    /traders/:id(.:format)      traders#show
                PUT    /traders/:id(.:format)      traders#update
                DELETE /traders/:id(.:format)      traders#destroy
          wants GET    /wants(.:format)            wants#index
                POST   /wants(.:format)            wants#create
       new_want GET    /wants/new(.:format)        wants#new
      edit_want GET    /wants/:id/edit(.:format)   wants#edit
           want GET    /wants/:id(.:format)        wants#show
                PUT    /wants/:id(.:format)        wants#update
                DELETE /wants/:id(.:format)        wants#destroy
            has GET    /has(.:format)              has#index
                POST   /has(.:format)              has#create
         new_ha GET    /has/new(.:format)          has#new
        edit_ha GET    /has/:id/edit(.:format)     has#edit
             ha GET    /has/:id(.:format)          has#show
                PUT    /has/:id(.:format)          has#update
                DELETE /has/:id(.:format)          has#destroy
           root        /                           static_pages#index
    add_traders        /add_traders(.:format)      traders#new
                       /traders(.:format)          traders#index
        add_has        /add_has(.:format)          has#new
                       /has(.:format)              has#index
      add_wants        /add_wants(.:format)        wants#new
                        /wants(.:format)            wants#index
```

**EDIT 3**
New Route after adding the Inflections code snippet.  "Has" routes are looking better but now I'm getting this error on any localhost:3000 page

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"has"}
```

Here are the new routes:

```
    traders GET    /traders(.:format)          traders#index
            POST   /traders(.:format)          traders#create
 new_trader GET    /traders/new(.:format)      traders#new
edit_trader GET    /traders/:id/edit(.:format) traders#edit
     trader GET    /traders/:id(.:format)      traders#show
            PUT    /traders/:id(.:format)      traders#update
            DELETE /traders/:id(.:format)      traders#destroy
      wants GET    /wants(.:format)            wants#index
            POST   /wants(.:format)            wants#create
   new_want GET    /wants/new(.:format)        wants#new
  edit_want GET    /wants/:id/edit(.:format)   wants#edit
       want GET    /wants/:id(.:format)        wants#show
            PUT    /wants/:id(.:format)        wants#update
            DELETE /wants/:id(.:format)        wants#destroy
  has_index GET    /has(.:format)              has#index
            POST   /has(.:format)              has#create
    new_has GET    /has/new(.:format)          has#new
   edit_has GET    /has/:id/edit(.:format)     has#edit
        has GET    /has/:id(.:format)          has#show
            PUT    /has/:id(.:format)          has#update
            DELETE /has/:id(.:format)          has#destroy
       root        /                           static_pages#index
add_traders        /add_traders(.:format)      traders#new
                   /traders(.:format)          traders#index
    add_has        /add_has(.:format)          has#new
                   /has(.:format)              has#index
  add_wants        /add_wants(.:format)        wants#new
                   /wants(.:format)            wants#index
```

Comment: So I see those "ha" routes....  I'm sure that's the problem.  I'm new to rails.  What should I do about that?

Comment: Named routes like `new_ha` suggest that Rails naming inflection don't work well with your example. In all the names are very uncommon. You might consider using a `Demand` model and an `Offer` model, for which Rails would inflect names and routes correctly.

Comment: Thanks Thomas.  Any advice on modifying the routes with model names as-is?  I'm using a pretty complex algorithm that was built for me using these names and I was hoping to not have to change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a noun for the name of your resource, but if for some reason you really want to keep the current name, you could use the following hack: trick rails into thinking that the "singular" and "plural" of "has" are the same using the inflector module:

In configs/initializers/inflections.rb:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'has', 'has'
end
```

Comment: It would be better to use nouns though. Tricking a system can turn ugly in a later revision of code.

Comment: Ah now I'm getting this error since adding the inflections modification: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"has"}

Comment: Make sure that you see the line `has GET /has/:id(.:format) has#show` when running rake routes.

Comment: That does look to be in there...     has GET    /has/:id(.:format)          has#show

Comment: What's the context of the error? Are you attempting to render the same template in your original code or a different one? If different, please post it.

Comment: Same template.  The only thing I changed was to add the Inflections code snippet above.  I ran rake routes, restarted the server and tried to load localhost:3000 and receive this one error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17160/discussion-between-cdesrosiers-and-seths)